# Cannot loop through devices

Tags: python, adb

I'm trying to use [this library](https://github.com/google/python-adb) but I cannot access all my devices because of the error `LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT`s.

Here is my code:

```py
cmd = 'echo hello world'
for connectedDevice in adb_commands.AdbCommands.Devices() :
    device = adb_commands.AdbCommands()
    device.ConnectDevice(port_path=connectedDevice.port_path, rsa_keys=[self.signer])
    print device.Shell(command=cmd).strip()
    device.Close()
```

I can run the command only to the first device in generator object, when the loop arrive to the second device it fails with error described above.

Any way to solve this?

Comment: the cmd should be `'echo "hello world"'` ?

Comment: Not rilevant, it works anyway in the first device.

Comment: is both devices have the same OS ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've solved the issue replacing the USB Hub..
Don't know why, but it works now..